# How to remove all ads after watching a reward video for a particular session

Tags: java, android, admob

I want to remove all the ads for that particular session after a reward video ad and after the app reopen the ads will show again, how can I do that

i like how this app done it
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.fourapps.morseconverter

i have two ads, one is a banner ad and the second are interstitial ad

HomeActivity.java

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });

        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        intertitalAd();
```

---

```
private void copy() {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(HomeActivity.this);
            mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                    startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                    intertitalAd();
                }
            });
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));

        }
        ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", quotesTxt.getText());
        if (clipboardManager != null) {
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void share() {
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(HomeActivity.this);
            mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                    startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                    mInterstitialAd = null;
                    intertitalAd();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, quotesTxt.getText());
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to"));
                }
            });
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, quotesTxt.getText());
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to"));


        }

    }

 public void intertitalAd() {

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


        InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: - Save flag in shared preferences or database.  user watch ads or not.

Comment: @KishanViramgama thanks, but can you explain in further details if possible or give me some refrence

Comment: Check this link to get some ideas :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089735/after-watching-rewarded-video-how-to-stop-showing-all-ads-in-the-android-app-fo

Comment: yes i have go through that question but im not sure how do i implement it for a session